# Getting single column from an entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate

How can you get a single column back from a query instead of a whole object?

I could do something like this to get the whole object, but all I want is the names:

```
IList<Tribble> tribbles = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Tribble)).List<Tribble>();
IList<string> names = new List<string>();
foreach (Tribble t in tribbles) {
    names.Add(t.Name);
}
```

I would like to be able to specify additional criteria, so is it possible to just exclude certain columns from being retrieved?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the solution I eventually ended up using:

```
ICriteria c = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Tribble));
c.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Property("Name")));
IList<string> names = c.List<string>();
```

I got this idea from [this old StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695917/nhibernate-only-retrieve-specific-columns-when-using-critera-queries).

Answer (score 7):

Almost five years later..., this is what you could do using NHibernate.Linq:

```
IList<string> names = session.Query<Tribble>().Select(t => t.Name).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

What about executing a query by string?

```
IList<string> names = session.CreateQuery("select name from Tribbles").List<string>();
```

Comment: Technically, you actually would have to do this:
    IList<string> names = session.CreateQuery("select t.name from Tribbles t").List<strings>();

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
IQuery query = dao.GetQuery(@"SELECT u.Id
                                FROM UserImpl u
                               WHERE u.UserName = :username");
               query.SetParameter("username", username);
return (long)query.UniqueResult();
```

Answer (score -2):

You typically don't. It rarely makes sense to have a partially populated business object.

Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am using it throughout the entire program with dozens of classes, this is the only time I've needed to do this and it is necessary in this circumstance.

Comment: Can you explain further what the use case is?

Comment: Doesn't this happen all the time? For example, I want to display an Employee's details plus the name of its Office. I don't need the whole office, just the name.

Comment: @cbp: It does happen all the time. Assuming that Employee is mapped m:1 to Office, NHibernate will retrieve Office when the Employee is loaded using a join. When working with business objects you always return fully populated objects (there are exceptions, of course). That's just the way it is with object oriented programming.