# nHibernate to single column lookup table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I would like to have a simple lookup table in the database with a single numeric non-integer column.  While the column is currently a primary key, nHibernate complains if I specify the type as non-integer (I need it to be a decimal).  I can add a surrogate key column to this table, or is there a simple solution that I can implement with nHibernate to **manage (read/insert/delete)** the values in this table without needing a surrogate key column?

I guess I could use [this code to select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075623/nhibernate-getting-single-column-from-an-entity), but what about insert/delete?  What's the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate only complains if the specified keygenerator doesn't support the type. I guess you haven' specified any generator which defaults to `identity` which can only handle integral types. with `assigned` you could provide the ids

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```